# nodejs and undefined variable, possible scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have started learning Node JS today and have made a chatroom.

When a user connects, it sends their user information to Node and that will store that in a var called `user` which is created in the anonymous function of `io.on('connecting', function ...` so I can have multiples of them for multiple users (I think that would work)

When the user disconnects, I remove an object of their user from `usersOnline` which is indexed by their `user.id`

I keep getting this error that tells me it is undefined:

`Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projects/hbc_chat/index.js:28:27)`

The error is where I use `delete usersOnline[user.id]`

And here is the code:

```
// server user
    var srvUser = {
        id: 0,
        display_name: 'HabboCreate',
        fancy_display_name: 'HabboCreate',
        picture: 'http://www.habbocreate.com/userdata/uploads/2f48a19f199bb5f018b3089fd4967902'
    };
    var usersOnline = {};


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var user;

    socket.on('connected', function(userObj) {

        // store user
        user = userObj;
        // add to users online list
        usersOnline[user.id] = user;
        // send to clients
        updateUsersOnline();
        // send joined message
        sendMessage(srvUser, user.display_name + ' joined the chat');

        console.log(user.display_name + ' connected');      
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        try {
            // remove their user from the online list
            delete usersOnline[user.id];
            // send to client
            updateUsersOnline();        
            // send left message
            sendMessage(srvUser, user.display_name + ' left the chat');
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        }
    });
....
```

Comment: You're using socket.io, right? There shouldn't be an additional `connected` event after the `connection` event; are you seeing the `user.display_name + ' connected'` log?

Comment: That connection is just the socket io emiting the user object for the users online list

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation? Are you seeing the `user.display_name + ' connected'` log? What is the value of `userObj`?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a scope issue. Is it possible updateUsersOnline() changes the user info? I just ran this exact code, very similar to yours, without errors:

```
var usersOnline = {};
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var user;
  socket.on('connected', function (userObject) {
    user = userObject;
    console.log('user: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
    usersOnline[user.id] = user;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(usersOnline) + '\n');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    try {
      console.log('user: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
      delete usersOnline[user.id];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(usersOnline) + '\n');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err: ' + err);
    }
  });
});
```

I passed a user created like this in the client 'connected' event:

```
var userObject = {
  id: new Date(),
  display_name: 'some_name',
};

my_connection.emit('connected', userObject);
```

After the connected event I closed the connection. This is what the server logged:

```
user: {"id":"2016-12-17T04:49:05.123Z","display_name":"some_name"}
{"2016-12-17T04:49:05.123Z":{"id":"2016-12-17T04:49:05.123Z","display_name":"some_name"}}

user: {"id":"2016-12-17T04:49:05.123Z","display_name":"some_name"}
{}
```

No errors, so it seems something is removing the user object or at least its id property in between your connected and disconnect events.

Answer (score 0):

right, well I've figured out what was wrong.

It was where I was on the chatroom page, I would restart the node server, my JavaScript wouldnt emit the user details (It only done so upon load), so when i went to refresh or whatever, `disconnect` event wouldn't be able to find info in the `user` variable and error

My fix was to make a `request user` event client side and then emit that on the server when there's a new connection, as to not rely on the page load sending the details